# How to fix "Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value" error in flutter?

Tags: flutter, rest, mobile, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter.

I want to pass data from frontend to node.js backend through rest APIs(using post method). But it shows following error when app is executed.

[image]

This is the code I wrote so far. I tried to find what the error is, but unfortunately I could not find it. can somebody to help me to figure out this issue?

1. Model file

   ```
   DataModel dataModelFromJSON(String str) => DataModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(str));
   String dataModelToJson(DataModel data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

   class DataModel {
      DataModel({required this.title, required this.id});

      String title;
      String id;

      factory DataModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
          DataModel(title: json['title'], id: json['id']);

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {"name": title, "id": id};
    }
   ```
2. Error occurred page

   ```
   class PurchaseOrder extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _PurchaseOrderState createState() => _PurchaseOrderState();
   }

   Future<DataModel?> submitData(String title) async {
     var response = await http.post(
       Uri.http('176.12.10.0:8020', 'order/create'),
       body: {"title": title},
     );
     print(title);
     var data = response.body;
     print(data);

     if (response.statusCode == 201) {
       String responseString = response.body;
       return dataModelFromJSON(responseString);
     } else
       return null;
   }

   class _PurchaseOrderState extends State<PurchaseOrder> {
     String today = DateFormat('yMd').format(DateTime.now());
     late DataModel _dataModel;
     TextEditingController titleController = TextEditingController();

     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
       return Container(
         child: Column(
           children: [
             TextFormField(
               decoration: const InputDecoration(
                 hintText: 'Enter your email',
               ),
               controller: titleController,
             ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: OutlinedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      String title = titleController.text;
                      DataModel? data = await submitData(title);
                      setState(() {
                        _dataModel = data!;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Text("Submit"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
   }
   ```

I hope your help to fix this issue.
Thank you

**Edited:**
I did following changes to the code. Error is gone. But data have not passed to the backend. What can I do.

I changed,

```
_dataModel = data!;
```

to

```
if (data != null) {
   _dataModel = data;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid uploading code as an image. 
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question  . Good luck 

Comment: @novonimo Thank you for your information. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only null check operator in your code is `_dataModel = data!;`
That means your `submitData` method has returned a null value that was passed to data. Or when you put a null check operator you have to make sure the variable isn't null.

To avoid this error you could check if data is null and if true pass another value :

```
_dataModel = data ?? otherValue
```

Comment: Thank you @Tanguy for your help. I changed code and updated the question with what I recent did. Error is gone, but data not passed to the backend. How can I fix that issue?

Comment: @New Guy
What you mean is that your submitData method does not work as intended. This is another problem then. You should ask another question with the code of this function.

Comment: Okay @Tanguy I will mark this as resolved and ask another question with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that somewhere in your code you are doing something with a non-nullable type, but the value is actually null.
When you use `data!` for example, you are telling the compiler that `data` will not be null, but it actually is.

You could use `data ?? someValue` to have a fallback, in case `data` is null.

Comment: Thank you @alexn62 for your help. I changed code and updated the question with what I recent did. Error is gone, but data not passed to the backend. How can I fix that issue?

Answer (score 0):

I could fix "data not passing issue" also.

**What I did?**

I changed post request from,

```
var response = await http.post(
Uri.http('176.12.10.0:8020', 'order/create'),
body: {"title": title},
);
```

to

```
var response = await http.post(
Uri.parse('http://176.12.10.0:8020/order/create'),
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    body: jsonEncode({"title": title}),
);
```